# Pandas(python) indexing on column conflicts with row index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a date time index, and it seems that I can't add a column that happens to be the year.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

df = DataFrame({'2013' : [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=pd.date_range('2014-02-21', periods=4, freq='H'))
```

Now, df stores the following:

```
                     2013
2014-02-21 00:00:00     1
2014-02-21 01:00:00     2
2014-02-21 02:00:00     3
2014-02-21 03:00:00     4

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

Adding column '2015' works as expected:

```
df['2015'] = -1 # or df.loc[:, '2015'] = -1
```

Now, df stores:

```
                     2013  2015
2014-02-21 00:00:00     1    -1
2014-02-21 01:00:00     2    -1
2014-02-21 02:00:00     3    -1
2014-02-21 03:00:00     4    -1

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

However, adding '2014' in the same way won't work, because:

```
df['2014'] # Returns the entire df, because df is sliced on year?
```

and

```
df.loc[:, '2014'] = -1 # Throws a KeyError.
```

I think I'd rather not use join or merge, as these return copies. I'm afraid that adding *many (i.e., > 1e+5)* columns to df, each time (re)assigning to df, consumes too much memory. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a work-around for this could be first adding the column name to the data-frame:

```
>>> df = df.reindex_axis(df.columns.tolist() + ['2014', '2015'],
                         axis=1, copy=False)
>>> df
                     2013  2014  2015
2014-02-21 00:00:00     1   NaN   NaN
2014-02-21 01:00:00     2   NaN   NaN
2014-02-21 02:00:00     3   NaN   NaN
2014-02-21 03:00:00     4   NaN   NaN

>>> df['2015'] = -1
>>> df['2014'] = 0
>>> df
                     2013  2014  2015
2014-02-21 00:00:00     1     0    -1
2014-02-21 01:00:00     2     0    -1
2014-02-21 02:00:00     3     0    -1
2014-02-21 03:00:00     4     0    -1

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: It works. However, reindex_axis returns a new object each time I add a column like this. Doesn't that inflate memory usage, because each copy stores the entire data frame except for the new column(s)?

Comment: not sure about that; `copy=False` should reduce memory footprint. overall, it is much better not to use numbers as column names; pandas does a few _guessing / inferring_ when using numerical/date indexing; for example it would be better to call the columns as `yr2013`, `yr2014`, ...

Comment: I agree that it's better not to use numbers. Now, I'm adding underscores to column names (e.g., '_2014'), because I'm not sure about which column names I'll encounter. Thanks!